# Boundedness of series involving moduli of Maclaurin coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is a bounded in some region $|z|\leq  R,R>1 $ and analytic function and consider the Maclaurin series for $f$:
$$  f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n.$$ My question is:

If $a_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}\frac{|f^j(0)|}{j!}$,what  can we say about the convergence or boundedness of the partial sums of the series of $\sum_1^{\infty} a_j.$ 
**My thoughts so far**

For $f $ as given we have the Mclaurin series for $f$ is given by
$$  f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$
Since $f$ f is analytic and bounded  in $|z| \leq 1$  , we have :
$$ f(1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$
As f is analytic and  $f(1)$
is bounded this means the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ is convergent  to $f(1)$ and hence the series $$\left| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\right| $$ must be bounded   which requires  $$\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \rightarrow 0$$ as $n$ goes to infinity and hence  $$|\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}| \rightarrow 0$$ I have no idea how to investigate further the behavior of
$$\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}\frac{|f^j(0)|}{j!}$$

I will be highly obliged for any suggestions/hints!

Comment: Jean Marie,Kindly have a look at the problem

Comment: There is no way to notify a user who has not already contributed to this page, Agnost.

Comment: Let $b_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$; the convergence of $\sum b_nz^n$ for $|z|<R, R>1$ means that $|b_n|((1+R)/2)^n \to 0$ (so $|b_n|$ are exponentially small) so $\sum b_n/\sqrt {n+1}$ is absolutely convergent and even $\sum b_nn^k$ is absolutely convergent for a fixed $k$

Comment: Could you kindly explain a bit your explanation and assertations